# How to speed up windows7 when hard drive is corrupted?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, speed, file-corruption

I have installed windows7 home basic with 300 GB SATA hard drive. It is very slow in booting and also running slow. Is there any way to check if hard drive is corrupted? and if so how to recover it and speed up my laptop

Comment: If you just installed a new operating system, the probability that your issue is a corrupt drive is almost zero.

Comment: I need to replace Hard drive :(

Comment: Please provide with more details on your hardware and Windows installation. By knowing you have 300 GB SATA drive and Windows 7, there may be zillions of possible reasons why your system may be slow. Other users can't guess them all, and even if they did, it would take you years to check each one. :)

Comment: I have this laptop http://www.sony.co.in/product/vpceb34en/specs

Comment: If the HDD is failing then the only acceptable solution is to replace the HDD.  You can clear file system flags but if the HDD is actually failing, new instances of those flags will happen, or worst your data will be lost.

Comment: Finally Replace HDD and it is the solution..... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't 'really' fix a hard drive in a reliable manner. Use chkdsk to scan and attempt to recover. [From an older answer](https://superuser.com/a/338093/10165) - these switches are what you should look at

/R Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information

/b NTFS only: Clears the list of bad clusters on the volume and rescans all allocated and free clusters for errors. /b includes the functionality of /r. Use this parameter after imaging a volume to a new hard disk drive. Works only on vista or better.

The 'smart' thing to do really is to image the drive from linux with gddrescue, and then run checkdisk on the original drive. You might also want to try [hdtune](http://www.hdtune.com/) - there's a free version and it does smart checks, speed benchmarks and surface checks.

A drive with enough bad sectors to have performance issues shouldn't be relied on for anything important.

Assuming its not the drive, you might want to make use of xperf to work out what's the bottleneck - MSDN has a [series of blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2012/11/23/installing-the-windows-performance-toolkit-v5-0-wprui-wpr-xperf.aspx)s that cover it and [mozilla has a guide to useing it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Performance/Profiling_with_Xperf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiling_with_Xperf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a SMART tool, [free from Acronis](http://www.acronis.co.uk/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/)

Or, pay for [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) which is much more through.

Now, purists will say that a SMART tool is not a perfect solution to a hard drive's integrity however, from your question I think it will be more than enough.

If the hard drive is faulty, you don't repair it. You bin in and buy a new one!

Either way, take a back up now!

Comment: Drive Monitor won't "fix" any problems with the drive only report any S.M.A.R.T data for the HDD in question.  Running SpinRite can help even the worst drives, but only to the point where, you are able to duplicate the HDD using the proper tools.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively You can check Your HDD surface with HD Tune, then re-partition the drive and leave the bad area unpartitioned and make the partition to a clear area of the drive. But as others said, it's not a good idea to use that drive, data must be backed up, and the drive must be replaced.